# Loading stylesheets and JavaScript taking too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

What should I do to decrease load time?

```
<head>
    <title>NCI SwitchGears</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu/styles.css">
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="menu/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Firstly, load only one jQuery version. BTW, the second one will override any previously set jQuery method, as bootstrap js ones

Comment: Quite often you can delay the loading of JS files by placing them before the closing body tag `</body>`. There might be an exception if you need to do some feature detection or polyfill a feature but most of the time you're parsing and manipulating the DOM which requires the DOM to have been loaded. Including scripts at the end of your page or creating a load/init function will help defer the parsing and execution of your JS.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides a nice tool to help you speed up the loading times of your pages
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Here's another nice [online tool](http://gtmetrix.com/).

As a general rule:

- load 1 js files and 1 CSS file - compressed
- have your js at the bottom of the page, not in header
- load social tools/scripts via ajax, after page has load
- optimize the images/graphics you use on your template
- set proper expiration headers and caching options

More specific instructions for your pages you can find in the above tools.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're loading jQuery twice. Once locally, and once remotely.
2. Consider using Require.JS to load your JS on demand
3. Combine Style sheets to one request. Make sure you are using modular styles and again, load on demand.
4. JS move to footer where appropriate